# Ignoring exception from a finished function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I keep getting this error when this function executes.

> Ignoring exception from a finished function

What I'm I missing?

```
exports = module.exports =  functions.database.ref('/cards/{userId}/{id}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {

        const token = snap.val().token;

        const userId = context.params.userId;

        const stripeRef = admin.database().ref('/stripe').child(userId);

        return stripeRef.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

            let accountId =  snapshot.val().accountId;

            return stripe.accounts.createExternalAccount(
                accountId,
                { external_account: token },
                function(err, card) {
                    snap.ref.child('cardId').set(card.id);
                });
         });
    });
```

Comment: Does createExternalAccount actually return a promise?  I suspect not, since you're depending on receiving a callback rather than receiving a result from a promise.  If it doesn't return a promise, then your last return doesn't do anything useful, and the function terminates before the callback is received.

Comment: Thanks, can you post an example?

Comment: I'm getting the same error after removing the last return

Comment: Removing that return won't help you do the right thing, which is to return a promise that resolves only after ALL the async work is complete in the function.

Comment: I still don't get it! I'm an Ios dev. I'm new to this. Would you mind showing me some code or some reference?

Comment: Never mind, after some digging I've figured it out. Thanks for your insight

Answer (score 0):

use try and catch to log the errors manually, like

```
try {
  //code goes here
}
catch(error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```